# Is $\{x|x-1=3\}=4$ True or False?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that  $\{x|x-1=3\}=4$ ? I'm not sure if this is true, I think $\{x|x-1=3\}=\{4\}$  is correct because I think  $\{x|x-1=3\}$ denote a set so RHS should be a set too.

Am I right?

Comment: You should add some more details into your question: why do you think it is correct? It will be much more beneficial to help you with your thought process rather than provide you with an answer.

Comment: @Kman3 Ok, it is one part of a question in high school level. the other parts was easy. for example it asked to check whether $4\in\{\{4\}\}$ is correct or not and so on.

Comment: I meant add more about your thought process. We want to know **why** you think your answer is correct. Please add why you think it is correct into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LHS is a set containing the number $4$. This would be usually be represented as $\{4\}$. There can be some contexts where a set is known to only have one element, so that element is used as shorthand or a function is defined as whatever that singleton element is. For example, if $f(x)=x-1$, then technically $f^{-1}(3)$ is the set containing 4, but you’d often see it being shown as just 4 itself since the inverse is unique.